# Using position absolute and relative in block container without giving height in Apache FOP

Tags: apache-fop

I am having problem in apache-fo, In General HTML & CSS if we give position:absolute to a div, it will take from its parent Top and Left, But Same thing if I give position: absolute to a particular block container in Apache FO, it taking from the Page Top & Left.If i give height, then it will come fine. but my content are coming dynamically, so i can't give height.

**For Example:**

```
<fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">


<fo:block-container width="100%" color="rgb(0, 0, 0)">
<fo:block>

<fo:block-container>
<fo:block-container width="50%" left="1in" top="1in" position="absolute"><fo:block>First Block</fo:block></fo:block-container>
<fo:block-container width="50%" left="2in" top="3in" position="absolute"><fo:block>Second Block</fo:block></fo:block-container>
</fo:block-container>

<fo:block-container>

<fo:block-container width="50%" left="1in" top="1in" position="absolute"><fo:block>Third Block</fo:block></fo:block-container>
<fo:block-container width="50%" left="2in" top="2in" position="absolute"><fo:block>Fourth Block</fo:block></fo:block-container>
</fo:block-container>

</fo:block>
</fo:block-container>

</fo:flow>
```

**In Given Example:** I am giving postion absolute to block container and top 1in; and left 1in; Instead of taking 1in from top & left from their parent, It taking 1in from top & left from top block Container.

I want output like After First Block, Second Block will display after 1in from Top & 1in from Left of First Block. But now it showing all the First Block, Second Block, Third Block, Fourth Block are coming in the Same postion, and taking Top & Left 1in from the Top Block Container. I can't give height. please give me some solution without giving height.

Comment: Please [edit your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34743147/edit) instead of creating a new one which is almost identical.

Comment: @ lfurini :  Would you please tell me how to solve this problem without giving height.

Comment: I wrote an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34948227/4453460) to your original question. I think this one should really be deleted.

Comment: @ lfurini : Thanks for reply.. But its not working in my scenario. If i have two divs giving left - 0, and 2nd div have left 3in, having top, the first div coming to accurately, but the 2nd div coming to the below of first div.